# Textarea not responding to css

Tags: html, css

all i'm trying to do here is simply add my css to my textarea but for some reason it isn't responding to it. Is there a particular way to do this as it's very odd that this isn't working. Probably a very simple answer here any clues guys?

```css
input[type="textarea"] {
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: none;
  border: none;
  overflow: auto;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="MyDoc.php" autocomplete="off">
  <textarea name="tb_A1" cols="1" rows="2"></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: why do you have width and height set up in css? textarea dimension is set by rows and cols

Comment: Style it with `textarea { ... }` not with `input[type="textarea"]`

Comment: `<textarea />` != `<input />`

Comment: Obvious mistake. I'm setting width and height because this is just an example and I needed them set in my project. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your CSS is incorrect. The field is not an `input`, it's a `textarea`:

```css
textarea {
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: none;
  border: none;
  overflow: auto;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="MyDoc.php" autocomplete="off">
  <textarea name="tb_A1" cols="1" rows="2"></textarea>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> input[type="textarea"] {
> ```

You are matching `input` elements, with a `type` attribute which has the value `textarea`.

> ```
> <textarea name="tb_A1" cols="1" rows="2"></textarea>
> ```

That is a **textarea** element, not an input element. It doesn't have a type attribute at all.

Your selector should be:

```
textarea {
```